# Getting an absolute PHP URL for a file directory listing in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, url, joomla, path, directory

I'm trying to use a PHP script in conjunction with Flexslider in Joomla 2.5 to be able to autoload slideshows and thumbnail slider nav from a folder without having to code it out for each slideshow, as described in part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219144/extra-thumbnail-nav-images-in-flexslider-loaded-from-folder-by-php).

I have tried to implement several different methods both Joomla specific and just to PHP, but I sense I am not incorporating them correctly.

```
1)
    $path = JPATH_COMPONENT; 

2)
    $path = JURI::root();

3)
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
4)
    <?php
    define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
    define('ROOT_URL', substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, - (strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) - strlen(ROOT_DIR))));
    ?>
```

If anyone can show me how to make any of these or another method play nice with:

```
$imgdir = 'flex/demo/images/'; //Pick your folder
```

So that one of Joomla's pretend urls for sub-menu items doesn't look for it in a directory that doesn't exist, that would be just too great.

As shown in the linked article, the whole script I'm using is stuck in via Jumi as thus:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flex/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

 <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

  <!-- FlexSlider -->
  <script defer src="flex/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
<?php
$imgdir = 'flex/demo/images/'; //Pick your folder
$allowed_types = array('jpg','jpeg','gif'); //Allowed types of files
$dimg = opendir($imgdir);//Open directory
while($imgfile = readdir($dimg))
{
  if( in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-3)),$allowed_types) OR
      in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-4)),$allowed_types) )
/*If the file is an image add it to the array*/
  {$a_img[] = $imgfile;}
}
echo "<ul class=\"slides\" >";

 $totimg = count($a_img);  //The total count of all the images
//Echo out the images and their paths incased in an li.
 for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<li><img src='" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></li>";}
echo "</ul>";

     echo "</div>";
       echo "<div id=\"carousel\" class=\"flexslider\">";

echo "<ul class=\"slides\" >";

 $totimg = count($a_img);  //The total count of all the images
//Echo out the images and their paths incased in an li.
 for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<li><img src='" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></li>";}
echo "</ul>";
?>
        </div>

<script>
 $(window).load(function(){
      $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
      });

      $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        sync: "#carousel",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**UPDATE** - **RESOLVED**

I initially mis-worded my question, I was having trouble getting the correct URL, not path for the images. At some point it was adding in a Joomla generated directory between my desired directory for the images and the images path. For some reason either I didn't interpret that correctly or it seems to have gone away by itself.

I needed to add a leading '/' but it wouldn't let me add it into the line:

```
$imgdir = 'flex/demo/images/'; //Pick your folder
```

So I addressed my problem by changing this:

```
//Echo out the images and their paths incased in an li.
 for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<li><img src='" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></li>";}
echo "</ul>";
```

to:

```
//Echo out the images and their paths incased in an li.
 for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<li><img src='/" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></li>";}
echo "</ul>";
```

in the two instances it occurs in the code for outputting the url to the img src.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Please use JUri:base() to get the base [URI](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/base) of your Joomla site.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo JUri:base(); ?>flex/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Change

```
$imgdir = 'flex/demo/images/'; //Pick your folder
```

to

```
$imgdir = JPATH_ROOT.'/flex/demo/images/'; //Pick your folder
```

These constants are defined for use in Joomla and extensions: [Constants](http://docs.joomla.org/Constants)

Comment: Thank you for your response, this seems very close to what I need. Unfortunately, the leading '/' doesn't seem to be making it through to the output page.

Comment: Okay, I was editing the wrong file, the issue I realize now is that I don't need the Base path inserted for $imgdir, I need the base URL. I tried using the echo JUri::base(); and without echo in the $imgdir = statement but no such luck, can it be used in that sort of statement?